# Unable to access static bool in Telegram Bot windows service

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Im unable to call a bool from a windows service but works in winforms.
here is the bool.

```
        public static bool IsUserRegistered(long UserId)
        {
            List<TelegramUser> UserDb = new List<TelegramUser>();
            string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(GlobalStrings.File_UserDB);
            UserDb = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TelegramUser>>(json);
            TelegramUser selectedUser = UserDb.Find(u => u.ChatID == UserId);
            return selectedUser != null;
        }
```

and here is the code from windows service

```
  static async Task OnMessage(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
                bool UserOrGuest = false;
                if (update.Message is Message message)
                    {
                        UserOrGuest = Users.IsUserRegistered(6122562837);
                        SendMessage(update.Message, "Registered: "+ UserOrGuest.ToString());
                    }
        }
```

if I comment out UserOrGuest = Users.IsUserRegistered(6122562837); it works.
and if i call Users.IsUserRegistered(6122562837) from a winforms application it works.
i am calling other values which read from the registry and that works.

unless Json cant work in async methods?

EDIT: The service freezes/Doesnt process anything.
IsUserRegistered is not returning a value.

Comment: it is not clear how it "does not work"... does it throw an exception? does it return the wrong value? you need to provide a fully reproducible example otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: you are right. editted.

Answer (score 0):

OK! So turns out GlobalStrings.File_UserDB which was using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory ,returned as C:\ but in winforms it returns as the actual executable path.